# Sending sssd.log to syslog

Tags: logging, syslog, sssd, splunk, centralized-logging

How do I configure SSSD to send sssd.log logs to syslog? I would like to include the DEBUB SSSD logs as well. We would like to feed the sssd logs to Splunk. Our systems are already configured to send syslog to Splunk Security Module. So we would like to use that setup, instead of the Splunk Forwarder.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL-7, edit `/etc/systemd/system/sssd.service.d/journal.conf`, uncomment the two lines there and then restart sssd in order to send the logs to journald.